# MySQL (WordPress) Illegal mix of collations error when attempting to compare post_type to 'string' in DELETE trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, collation

MySQL throws a
`#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`
when I delete a row in wp_posts with the below BEFORE DELETE trigger:
`BEGIN SET @POST_TYPE = OLD.post_type; SET @DESIRED_TYPE =  'wc_user_membership'; IF (@POST_TYPE = @DESIRED_TYPE) THEN SET @USER_ID = OLD.post_author; SET @META = 'active_member'; DELETE FROM` wp_usermeta`WHERE`user_id`= @USER_ID AND`meta_key `= @META; END IF; END`
I only have 4 hours of familiarity with collations, as I've been frantically Googling to try to find a solution, so I'm hoping to find some help here. MySQL version is 8.0.31-23.

I've tried using CAST, CONVERT, and COLLATE both around setting the variables and in the IF condition with multiple settings. I've tried changing the collation of one variable and not the other, and changing the collation of both to something new/different like binary or 'utf8mb4_unicode-ci'/'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'. And I don't want to change the collation of the column on the wp_posts table, because that sounds like a bad idea.
All of the solutions I've found have been in reference to people working with multiple languages in SELECT statements, so I'm guessing there's a difference in the syntax for triggers, but I'm not that good with MySQL yet. lol
Maybe it could even be a caching issue with the database? If the trigger isn't updating effectively, but if I swap the variable placements around in the IF condition from:
`IF (@POST_TYPE = @DESIRED_TYPE) THEN`
to
`IF (@DESIRED_TYPE = @POST_TYPE) THEN`
the placement of the identified collations in the error message changes to
`#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`
which makes sense. I can see that the collation of post_type column in wp_posts is set to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, there is no syntax difference here for triggers. You just need to find the right collation to use with the collate keyword for the @DESIRED_TYPE variable.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. It turned out to be as simple as changing the database connection collation to match the utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci preference of WordPress. Then removing and re-adding the trigger.